# What is "reverse" about "reverse bayonet" circular connectors?

Tags: connector

Some MIL-style circular connectors with bayonet fastening are presented as "reverse bayonet". For example, [Amphenol GT](https://www.amphenol.com/node/4771). The fastening direction is clockwise, just like any other bayonet connector. Why are such connectors labeled as "reverse"? What is reversed about them?
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this video: https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/which-locking-mechanisms-for-connectors-should-i-choose The difference is where the pin "guide" is located. For reverse byonet it is on the static connector, for the byonet it is on the rotating part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "reverse" appears to have to do with the locking pins.

[image: BNC Connectors]

On a BNC connector, a popular bayonet-style connector, note that the male connector (bottom) has the slots on the locking ring to accept the female pins.

On the Amphenol connector you are inquiring about, the male connector has the pins on the ring instead.

Although the [datasheet](https://www.amphenol-industrial.com/images/catalogs/RADSOK.pdf) does not explain this, there are additional images and information which may be of use.

Comment: One benefit to the reverse bayonet is that when the connection is assembled, there aren't any exposed slots on the exterior to collect dust or water.

Comment: @Theodore An excellent point. I can appreciate why they are favored in industry and aerospace applications.

Comment: DUH!   I feel stupid. Thank you!